# How to speed up the formation of excel file?

Tags: java, excel, file, apache-poi

I have such a code that generates using the POI library. The list contains 250,000 lines. The formation of an Excel file takes 30-40 minutes. Reading about POI, I realized that this is not normal. How to speed up the process?

```
private void create(List<User> list) throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Statistic");
    var rowCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);

        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
        
        XSSFCell loginCell = row.createCell(0);
        loginCell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getLogin());

        //...

        XSSFCell amountSpecCell = row.createCell(9);
        amountSpecCell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getLevel());
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("myfilenew.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using concurrent programming? {https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html}}

Comment: Try starting your Java application with more memory. It is entirely possible it spends a lot of time on GC (large Excel files take quite a lot of memory in Java). Also try switching to a streaming write of the Excel file. And finally, try wrapping the `FileOutputStream` in a `BufferedOutputStream` (though my guess is the time is spent in the loop, and not writing to disk).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i have last mac with 32GB memory

Comment: I agree @MarkRotteveel, the code you have written does not seem to be slow. control your List<User> list. how fast it is created? if this is the problem concurrent programming would help you a lot.

Comment: What do you think `sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);` will do? There `i` would must be a column index of the sheet. But it isn't like that in your code. And `Sheet.autoSizeColumn` is time consuming. It should be done once when the sheet is filled with data and not thousands of time within the loop. You seems to have 10 columns (0 to 9), so try `sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);...sheet.autoSizeColumn(9);` outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @IlyaY Your Mac having 32GB doesn't mean that your java process gets a lot of memory. That depends on the Java version and the options you used when starting. That said, I guess Axel's suggestion it is the autoSizeColumn is the more likely cause.

Comment: @AxelRichter i did autoSizeColumn() for each column and it slowed down the process even more. I then I removed all autoSizeColumn() and now it's going fast. in 20 seconds

Comment: `Sheet.autoSizeColumn` will always be time consuming. It needs traversing all filled cells in the given column, get the needed width of the cell content using `FontMetrics` to get the needed column width to be able to show the widest cell content.

Comment: You should use SXSSFWorkbook (prepend every XSS class with S to get SXSS) (https://andriymz.github.io/misc/apache-poi-slow-excel-generation/).